# Ruby faraday openweathermap api configure block and then conn.get block

Tags: ruby, api, openweathermap, faraday, ruby-block

```
require 'faraday'
require 'pry'

ENV['API'] = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"



conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5') do|faraday|
  faraday.request  :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
  faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
  faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with 
  Net::HTTP
end

response = conn.get do |req|
            req.url '/weather'
            req.params['q'] = 'oskaloosa'
            req.params['APPID'] = ENV['API']
            req.params['units'] = 'metric'
           end
```

The above is the current configure block and request block I have been using, unfortunately it is not producing the results I want.

I receive:

```
#<Faraday::Response:0x00007f7f4aa331f0
 @env=
  #<struct Faraday::Env
   method=:get,
   body=
    "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\r\n<body 
bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr>
<center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n",
   url=
    #<URI::HTTP http://api.openweathermap.org/weather?
APPID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&q=oskaloosa&units=metric>,
   request=
    #<struct Faraday::RequestOptions
     params_encoder=nil,
     proxy=nil,
     bind=nil,
     timeout=nil,
     open_timeout=nil,
     boundary=nil,
     oauth=nil,
     context=nil>,
   request_headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.13.1"},
   ssl=
    #<struct Faraday::SSLOptions
     verify=nil,
     ca_file=nil,
     ca_path=nil,
     verify_mode=nil,
     cert_store=nil,
     client_cert=nil,
     client_key=nil,
     certificate=nil,
     private_key=nil,
     verify_depth=nil,
     version=nil>,
   parallel_manager=nil,
   params=nil,
   response=#<Faraday::Response:0x00007f7f4aa331f0 ...>,
   response_headers=
    {"server"=>"openresty",
     "date"=>"Sun, 12 Nov 2017 22:55:30 GMT",
     "content-type"=>"text/html",
     "content-length"=>"162",
     "connection"=>"close"},
    status=404,
   reason_phrase="Not Found">,
 @on_complete_callbacks=[]>
```

I first see a 404 response so its obvious the get request did not work correctly. Upon inspection I see that the final url is not encoding the params correctly. The url as of now is:
`#<URI::HTTP http://api.openweathermap.org/weather?APPID=95cade087f6f767d179feaa301816de4&q=oskaloosa&units=metric>`

when in reality the correct url I am trying to construct is:
`#<URI::HTTP http://api.openweathermap.org/weather?q=oskaloosa&APPID=95cade087f6f767d179feaa301816de4&units=metric>` .

Now I know I can string interpolate with `#{param['key'])` or #{@key}` , but I am trying to use solely block construction for this conn and request/response cycle.

Can anyone give me some advice or shed some light on this topic?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference between the two is supposed to be, but your desired URL 404s, too.

Comment: holy crap, thank you, you just pointed out the real problem in the urls. A new set of eyes really helped. So in the conn construct it has `/data/2.5` attached to the end. and in the request its removing it completely and replacing it with `/weather` I need `/data/2.5/weather?`

Comment: any idea why its detaching it from the conn constructor to the request/response cycle constructor? or do I remove `/data/2.5` from the conn constructor and add it to the response/request cycle object (`/data/2.5/weather`)?

Comment: I've never used Faraday, but it's possible it parses out the root URI and then you have to provide the path segments as arguments in your request/config block.

Comment: god dang, you were completely right, changing req.url in the request block to req.url = '/data/2.5/weather' and taking '/data/2.5' out of url in the conn constructor completely fixed it. Thank you so much for that small catch I kept looking over.

Comment: You might want to redact the API key from the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'faraday'
require 'pry'

ENV['API'] = "95cade087f6f767d179feaa301816de4"



conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://api.openweathermap.org') do |faraday|
  faraday.request  :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
  faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
  faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
end

response = conn.get do |req|
            req.url '/data/2.5/weather'
            req.params['q'] = 'oskaloosa'
            req.params['APPID'] = ENV['API']
            req.params['units'] = 'metric'
           end
```

response:

```
I, [2017-11-12T17:57:43.154891 #15447]  INFO -- : get http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=95cade087f6f767d179feaa301816de4&q=oskaloosa&units=metric
D, [2017-11-12T17:57:43.154968 #15447] DEBUG -- request: User-Agent: "Faraday v0.13.1"
I, [2017-11-12T17:57:43.717003 #15447]  INFO -- Status: 200
D, [2017-11-12T17:57:43.717153 #15447] DEBUG -- response: server: "openresty"
date: "Sun, 12 Nov 2017 23:57:50 GMT"
content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
content-length: "428"
connection: "close"
x-cache-key: "/data/2.5/weather?APPID=95cade087f6f767d179feaa301816de4&q=oskaloosa&units=metric"
access-control-allow-origin: "*"
access-control-allow-credentials: "true"
access-control-allow-methods: "GET, POST"
```

via @pdoherty926 in the comments above